# Prometheus increase function working wrongly

Tags: prometheus, counter, metrics, promql

I am measuring the number of times api is called using counter metric, and then using promql to write queries. I called the api 3 times. Increase function giving incorrect answers

query :- metric[10m:30s]
showing counter increased value by 3 from 65 to 68
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niqYh.png)

query :- increase(metric[1m])[10m:]
showing no increase
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX5EG.png)

query :- increase(metric[1m])[10m:30s]
showing increase of 6
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lOUL.png)

Why increase function did not show rise in 2nd query? Answer should have been 3
why increase function did not show rise of 6 rather than 3 in 3rd query?

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus calculates `increase(m[d])` at the given timestamp `t` in the following way:

1. It selects raw samples stored in the database for the metric `m` on the time range `(t-d ... t]`.
2. It removes e.g. `counter resets` from the selected raw samples individually per each [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series) matching `m`. The `counter reset` is the event when the [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) metric value resets to zero after the restart of the monitored service. For example, if a counter time series contains `10 20 5 15` values on the time range `(t-d ... t]`, then it is assumed that the counter was reset to 0 between 20 and 5 values. So the values are adjusted accordingly in order to remove the counter reset: `10 20 25 35`.
3. It calculates the difference between the last and the first raw sample on the time range `(t-d ... t]` individually per each matching time series.
4. If timestamps for the first and/or the last sample on the `(t-d ... t]` time range are located too far from the bounds of the time range, then [extrapolation](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) is applied to results calculated at step 3.

It is likely the step 4 led to unexpected results for your case. Another possible reason for unexpected `increase()` results is that Prometheus doesn't take into account the increase between the last sample just before the `(t-d ... t]` time range and the first sample inside the time range.

Prometheus developers [are aware of these issues](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) with `increase()` and `rate()` functions. There is [design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit) on how to address the issue.

In the meantime you can try using an alternative Prometheus-like solution - VictoriaMetrics. Its' `increase()` function implementation is free of the issues mentioned above.